# Firefox: stopping propagation of enter keypress on confirm popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm having a really strange problem only occuring in firefox. I have a run of the mill dialog:

```
var cnf = confirm(message);

if(cnf) {
    blah blah
}
```

The problem is I also have a keyup handler on the document that somehow fires when the user types enter to confirm the dialog.

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {          
    console.log('someone hit ' + e.which);   
});
```

When the user hits enter to confirm, the console also logs "someone hit 13" which doesn't happen in any other browser (and AFAIK shouldn't happen)

Is there any way for me to prevent propagation of the keydown event or somehow avoid this behavior?

Here's a jsfiddle depicting the problem: [clicky](http://jsfiddle.net/8vFjR/1/)

Comment: e.stopPropagation() should help

Comment: e.stopPropagation() on what? I want to stop propagation at the dialog level.

Comment: This does not seem to show anything in the console http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/R4Lsd/show - can you make your own?

Comment: I can not see the problem but another solution apart from answer already given is to check the target of the keypress and see if it has parent element that is a confirm dialog. Can not check the selector to use without ability to re-produce the issue. Which Firefox version are you using and on which OS?

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly wrote keydown instead of keyup. Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vFjR/1/) that I forked from mplungjan's to cut out some failure points

Comment: @amitamb I've checked the target of the event and it's whatever element has focus at the time, nothing to trace it to any confirm dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution I think would be to over-ride confirm method in Firefox.

```
// Ideally you should use feature detection but can't think of a better way
if ( true ) { // Check for firefox like $.browser.mozilla
  (function(window){
    var _confirm = window.confirm;
    window.confirm = function(msg){
      var keyupCanceler = function(ev){
          ev.stopPropagation();
          return false;
      };
      document.addEventListener("keyup", keyupCanceler, true);
      var retVal = _confirm(msg);
      setTimeout(function(){
        document.removeEventListener("keyup", keyupCanceler, true);
      }, 150); // Giving enough time to fire event
      return retVal;
    };
  })(window);
}
```

Above code will disable any keyup events from reaching to DOM elements by using Capturing phase.

Please check this updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mTrPQ/2/

Comment: this worked nicely without having to change the code in a hundred places.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution it comes to my mind is adding a flag: when the confirm dialog is going to be shown, set the flag to true, and check it in the event listener method.

```
var flagDialog=true;
var cnf = confirm(message);
flagDialog=false;

if(cnf) {
    blah blah
}

. . .    

$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
    if (flag) {
        e.stopPropagating();
        return;
    } else {
        console.log('someone hit ' + e.which);   
    }
});
```

**Latest Update**: I've tried to modify the confirm default function but it seems it won't work: http://jsfiddle.net/8vFjR/4/

Comment: I'm hoping for a cleaner solution than this to be honest. While it would work (and does actually, i've tested) it would mean hundreds of changes in the code that I just don't have the time to do.

Comment: @Pablo Please check comments on original question. Event is keyup instead of keydown.

Comment: I've also edited my opening post to include a fiddle. check it out, it's a fork from @mplungjan

Comment: Checked and confirmed... I tried another approach but it did not work as expected :(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue and I checked e.target is the button which is being clicked (the "click me" button). So you can check if the target is that button and accordingly you can proceed.

```
$(function() {
    var $btn = $('#btn');
    $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
        if(e.target == $btn[0]) return; // Added line
        console.log('someone hit ' + e.which);   
    });
});

function clickMe() {
    var cnf = confirm("Yes?");
    if(cnf) {
        console.log('someone confirmed');
    }
}
```

You can check here also:
http://jsfiddle.net/8vFjR/5/

Hope it helps